# ComboBox: Set text of boxitem based on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate, multibinding

I have a `ComboBox` with a `DataTemplate` assigned to it.
The `DataTemplate` looks like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBox_EntityCreation_GroupSelect_Style" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}    {1} Members">
                            <Binding Path="Name"/>
                            <Binding Path="MemberCount"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I would like to achieve that "Members" is replaced with "Member" if `MemberCount == 1`.
So I need something like an if-else clause in XAML.

Is there any way to achieve this in XAML?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot do this in xaml only. You could use a [MultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.converter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
<Window.Resources>
    <c:MemberConverter x:Key="myMemberConverter"/>
...
</Window.Resources>

...
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myMemberConverter}">
        <Binding Path="Name"/> 
        <Binding Path="MemberCount"/> 
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

```
public class NameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if((values[1] as int) == 1)
        {
           return (values[0].ToString()) + "\t" + values[1].ToString() + "Member";
        }
        return (values[0].ToString()) + "\t" + values[1].ToString() + "Members";            
    }

    /* ... */   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}    {1} Member{2}">
    <Binding Path="Name"/>
    <Binding Path="MemberCount"/>
    <Binding Path="MemberPluralS"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

with an additional property in your ViewModel

```
public string MemberPluralS
{
   get { return MemberCount != 1 ? "s" : string.Empty; }
}
```

**Edit**

Here a XAML solution (maybe not the best)

```
<TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Style>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="Text">
            <Setter.Value>
               <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}    {1} Members">
                  <Binding Path="Name"/>
                  <Binding Path="MemberCount"/>
               </MultiBinding>                           
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MemberCount}" Value="1">
               <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name, StringFormat='{}{0}    1 Member'}" />
            </DataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```